# File_exists function do not work properly with relative paths through symlink directory

Tags: php

I created simple code which reproduces this issue:

```
<?php

exec('mkdir foo');
exec('mkdir foo/bar');
exec('touch foo/bar/example.txt');
exec('ln -s foo/bar symlink');
exec('mkdir not_symlink');

$dir1 = 'symlink/../foo/bar/example.txt';
$dir2 = 'not_symlink/../foo/bar/example.txt';
$dir3 = 'symlink/example.txt';
$dir4 = 'foo/bar/example.txt';
$dir5 = 'foo/bar/../bar/example.txt';
$dir6 = 'symlink';

var_dump(file_exists($dir1)); // false ???
var_dump(file_exists($dir2)); // true
var_dump(file_exists($dir3)); // true
var_dump(file_exists($dir4)); // true
var_dump(file_exists($dir5)); // true
var_dump(file_exists($dir6)); // true
```

Why file_exists return false for `$dir1`? I can't find any explanation in php documentation for this behaviour.

I tested this code on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Try `$dir1 = 'symlink/../../foo/bar/example.txt'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec('ln -s foo/bar symlink');
$dir1 = 'symlink/../foo/bar/example.txt';
```

After resolving the symlink, `$dir1` is `'foo/bar/../foo/bar/example.txt'`. Or, simplied `'foo/foo/bar/example.txt'`.

And that path does not exist.

Comment: I always thought that double dots are resolved before symlinks. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: That would allow you to use `symlink/../foo/bar` without actually creating `symlink` at all. I don't know how it actually works internally; I think the path is split by `/` then each piece from left to right is interpreted in the context of the path resolved until then. If a directory or a symlink having that name does not exist in the directory at hand (partially resolved path) then the entire path is invalid and the function returns error. The same happens when the component is a symlink and its destination does not exist. It also fails when it cannot enter to a directory (no `x` right).

Answer (score 0):

The path you are trying to resolve is wrong.

```
$ readlink -f symlink/../foo
/home/myuser/foo/foo
```

Add a `../`:

```
$ readlink -f symlink/../../foo/bar/example.txt
/home/myuser/foo/bar/example.txt
```